# Angular Material matInput content aligned to the right

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How do we align the input of matInput in Angular Material to the right?

My current code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="number" id="amount" placeholder="Amount"
    [ngModel]="entry.amount | number :'1.2-2'"
    (ngModelChange)='entry.amount=$event' />
</mat-form-field>
```

Desired output :

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the standard `text-align` CSS property should just work.

```
<input matInput class="right">

.right { text-align: right }
```

Comment: Needed a semicolon before it worked for me: .right { text-align: right; }

Comment: @Anders8 Only if you have other styles after it. On its own, the semicolon is not needed.